# Simple Android Program causes error

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm starting to code in android , but my first toast program causes an error: `Has Stopped Working`

I've submitted my code , hopefully you can help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText edit;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
}

View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                edit.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }; 
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error log as well to your question ?

Comment: post the error Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning onClickListener on views require Context of class(this/MainActivity.this/....), also don't use final if you have already declared your views.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText edit;
private Button btn;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     // if view is your button
     if(v == btn){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            edit.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Khalid Thankyou, for reminding me for implementing View.onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the btn is not null, add this line of code:

```
if(btn != null){
    btn.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got `NullPointerException`. Why? Look at below code block:

```
// your global variable
EditText edit;
// your local variable
final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

2 `edittext`s are 2 different objects. Hence, when you try to use your global `EditText` Which is not initialized before --> you got error. Just removing  `final EditText` in your local variable will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Remove from your code:

```
final Button
final EditText
```

Answer (score -1):

Because of your global reference it's not working. Remove global reference or you can do like...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText edit;
private Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                edit.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not specify your view in onClickListener, all the buttons will show a toast. It is very important to use if or switch to know which view has to perform what.

Comment: Yes, @W4R10CK, are you right. But he has only one button.

Answer (score -1):

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

These lines of code are causing the problem because you have already defined the variables btn and edit, hence there is no need to define them again. You could replace the above line with the following.

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

This should probably fix your problem. If not, just let us know.